# MIT opencourseware 18.01 Single variable calculus. Integration(Areas and Volumes). Recitation problem

Tags: calculus, integration, area, volume

The question:

Find the volume of the solid generated by rotating the region bounded by y=0 and y=sqrt(x)
around the line x=6.

My approach (1):

integrate w.r.t to y.

integrate limit from 0 to sqrt(6) of integrand pi*(y)^4 dy.

pi*(y^4) because radius would be y^2 and area would be pi*(y^4).

This gave the answer in decimal 55.4.

My approach(2):(USE SHELL METHOD)
So radius would (6-x)

height would sqrt(x)

width would be dx

so integrate limit from o to 6 of integrand (2*pi)(6-x)(sqrt(x))dx

The answer you get in decimal 147.75.

2 completely different answers from the 2 valid methods in my view. Can anyone please explain where I went wrong. The second answer is the correct one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your first calculation is wrong. The axis of rotation is $x=6$. It should be $\int_0^\sqrt 6\pi(6-y^2)^2\,dy$.